# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i f(g_i x) \geq 0$ holds for all $x \in G$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i \geq 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, abelian-groups

> **Problem statement:** Let $f(x) \geq 0$ be a nonzero, bounded, real function on an Abelian group $G$, $g_1, \ldots, g_k$ are given elements of $G$, and $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$ are real numbers. Prove that if $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i f(g_i \cdot x) \geq 0$$
> holds for all $x \in G$, then
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i \geq 0.$$

**My failed attempt**

We can suppose that $f(g_{1}) \geq 0$. Denote by $A_{n}$ the set of those elements that can be written in the form $g_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}, \ldots, g_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}$, where the maximum absolute value of the numbers $\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{k}$ is $n$, where $n > 0$ is an integer. Denote by $S(H)$ the sum $\sum_{x \in H} f(x)$ where $H$ is a finite set. In $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S(A_{n+1}) - S(A_{n-1})}{S(A_{n})} = 0$$ holds, since if for some $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $n > 0$, $$\frac{S(A_{n+1}) - S(A_{n-1})}{S(A_{n})} > \epsilon$$.

would hold, then

$$S(A_{n+1}) > S(A_{n-1}) + \epsilon S(A_{n}) \geq (1 + \epsilon) S(A_{n-1})$$

and so

$$S(A_{2n+1}) \geq (1+ \epsilon)^{n} S(A_{1})$$

Comment: @RiverOfTears You need to suppose $\lambda_i\geqslant 0$ to write $\lambda_i f(g_ix)\leqslant C\lambda_i$. So you in fact wrote that $$ 0\leqslant C\sum_{i=1}^k|\lambda_i|. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed
$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{S(A_{n+1})-S(A_{n-1})}{S(A_n)}=0. $$
If it were not the case, we would have $S(A_{2n+1})\geqslant (1+\varepsilon)^nS(A_1)$ for an infinite number of $n$, and for some fixed $\varepsilon>0$ as you wrote, which is in contradiction with the upper bound
$$ S(A_n)\leqslant\|f\|_{\infty}\#A_n\leqslant\|f\|_{\infty}(2n+1)^k. $$
We have
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_iS(g_iA_n)=\sum_{x\in A_n}\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i f(g_ix)\geqslant 0 $$
by hypothesis therefore
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\geqslant\frac{1}{S(A_n)}\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i(S(A_n)-S(g_iA_n)). $$
Note that $|S(A_n)-S(g_iA_n)|\leqslant S(A_{n+1})-S(A_{n-1})$ so
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\geqslant -\frac{1}{S(A_n)}\sum_{i=1}^k|\lambda_i|(S(A_{n+1})-S(A_{n-1})). $$
Taking the limit $n\rightarrow +\infty$ gives you the desired inequality
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\geqslant 0. $$

Comment: You made it extremely simple(+1)